# Weighted power sum system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, least-squares

Let the following weighted power sum system of equations on $x_j$, with $j= 1,2,\ldots, n$ :

> $$\alpha_{11} \cdot x_1 + \alpha_{12}\cdot x_2 + \cdots + \alpha_{1n}\cdot x_n  = b_1$$
> $$\alpha_{21}\cdot x_1^2 + \alpha_{22}\cdot x_2^2 + \cdots + \alpha_{2n} \cdot x_n^2  = b_2$$
> $$\vdots$$
> $$\alpha_{m1}\cdot x_1^m + \alpha_{m2}\cdot x_2^m + \cdots + \alpha_{mn}\cdot x_n^m  = b_m,$$

where $\alpha_{ij},  b_i, x_j \in \mathbb{C}$ and $m \geq n$. I am looking for a method that solves this system in the **least-squares sense**.

Any idea of how to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: IMHO, nothing can be said in general. Like for a linear system, if $m<n$, an infinite set of solutions is likely. If $m>n$ zero solution is likely. But as long as we have no information about the matrix $[\alpha_{ij}]$...

Comment: @JeanMarie, what about a least squares approach?

Comment: In this case, what would you consider as "points" ? Moreover, if $m,n$ are of the order of few dozens, the error in $x_1^{30}$ for example will be so huge as compared with the error in $x_1$... any approximate solution will not be reliable. Maybe, give the origin of your problem.

Comment: I didn't understand your question about "points"? In my case, $x_j$ are complex exponentials , so accuracy won't be a problem with approximation solutions. By the way, I don't want be rude but I think that it is me to judge whether an approximate method is good or not. Just give me one if you know it.

Comment: Maybe, attempt to use the multivariate version of [Newton's approximation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization). You may know it already.